# Mockery: Testing chained method calls with different return values (here: Symfony ProcessBuilder)

Tags: php, symfony, mockery

I'm trying to test a method that creates 2+ [Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) objects (also see [API docs](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.html)) using Symfony's [ProcessBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Process/ProcessBuilder.html) and I've run into problems when trying to return different mock process objects. In fact, I'm a bit unsure about whether [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) can even do this.

**Is it possible to choose the value in Mockery's `andReturn()` based on the call chain of an object (including arguments)?**

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$processBuilderMock
    ->shouldReceive('setPrefix("test")->add("-f")->getProcess')
    ->andReturn($testProcess);
```

**Full example:**
The following code creates a file `/tmp/dummy` if it does not exist. It uses the two commands `test -f /tmp/dummy` and `touch /tmp/dummy` for that (I know it's a dumb example).

```
<?php
class Toggler
{
    public function toggleFile(ProcessBuilder $builder)
    {
        $testProcess = $builder
            ->setPrefix('test')->setArguments(array('-f', '/tmp/dummy'))
            ->getProcess();

        $testProcess->run();

        if (!$testProcess->isSuccessful()) { // (a)
            $touchProcess = $builder
                ->setPrefix('touch')->setArguments(array('/tmp/dummy'))
                ->getProcess();

            $touchProcess->run();
            return $touchProcess->isSuccessful(); // (b) 
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

To test all cases, I need to be able to mock the `Process` objects for the corresponding commands `test` and `touch` (here: `$testProcess` and `$touchProcess`). Ideally, the test code for this would look like this:

```
<?php
public function testToggleFileFileDoesNotExist()
{
    $testProcess = \Mockery::mock('\Symfony\Component\Process\Process');
    $testProcess->shouldReceive('isSuccessful')->andReturn(false); // (a)
    $testProcess->shouldReceive('run');

    $touchProcess = \Mockery::mock('\Symfony\Component\Process\Process');
    $touchProcess->shouldReceive('isSuccessful')->andReturn(false); // (b)
    $touchProcess->shouldReceive('run');

    $builder = \Mockery::mock('\Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessBuilder');
    $builder->shouldReceive('setPrefix("test")->getProcess')->andReturn($testProcess);  // (c) Doesn't work!
    $builder->shouldReceive('setPrefix("touch")->getProcess')->andReturn($touchProcess); // (c) Doesn't work!

    $toggler = new Toggler();
    $this->assertTrue($toggler->toggleFile($builder)); // see (b)
}
```

However, since **Mockery does not allow arguments in the call chain**, I'm a bit lost on how to test such a scenario. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly terrible, but you *could* try entering each step of the call chain separately and having it return the mock $builder. Which process is returned at the end would depend on the order of the calls.

```
$builder->shouldRecieve('setPrefix')->with('test')->andReturn($builder);
$builder->shouldRecieve('setPrefix')->with('touch')->andReturn($builder);

$builder->shouldRecieve('getProcess')
    ->andReturnValues(array($testProcess, $touchProcess));
```

This feels very messy, but it's the only way I've been able to find so far. (If you came up with anything better since posting this, I'd be curious to see.)